# Proving unequality for two-stage stochastic LP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Given the following **deterministic equivalent** definition of **two-stage** stochastic linear problems:

$K = min_{x} \left\{c^Tx + \sum_{k=1}^{M} p_kq_k^Ty_k |\ Ax = b; \ T_kx + W_ky_k = h_k; y_k\geq 0, x\geq 0 \,\,\forall\  k=1,2,\ldots M \right\}$

where $(T_k, W_k, h_k, y_k)$ occurs with probability $p_k > 0$ $\ \forall\ k=1,2,\ldots, M$

Note that the term $\sum_{k=1}^{M} p_kq_k^Ty_k$ with the condition $T_kx + W_ky_k = h_k; y_k\geq 0$ is actually equivalent to the second-stage problem in SLP:

$E(Q(x,\zeta))$, where $Q(x,\zeta) = min_{y} \left\{q^Ty | Tx + Wy = h, y\geq 0\right\}$, and $\zeta = (q,T,w,h)$.

Now, I want to prove the following claim: For $M\geq 2$, 
$$K\neq  p_1 min_{x} \left\{c^Tx + q_1^Ty_1 |\ Ax = b; \ T_1x + W_1y_1 = h_1; y_1\geq 0, x\geq 0\right\} + \ldots  + p_M min_{x} \left\{c^Tx + q_M^Ty_M |\ Ax = b; \ T_Mx + W_My_M = h_M; y_M\geq 0, x\geq 0\right\}$$

**1st approach:**

First, since $\sum_{k=1}^{M}p_k = 1$, I planned to establish $min_{x} \left\{c^Tx + \sum_{k=1}^{M} p_kq_k^Ty_k |\ Ax = b; \ T_kx + W_ky_k = h_k; y_k\geq 0, x\geq 0 \,\,\forall\  k=1,2,\ldots M \right\}> \sum_{k=1}^{M} min_{x} \left\{p_kc^Tx + p_kq_k^Ty_k |\ Ax = b; \ T_kx + W_ky_k = h_k; y_k\geq 0, x\geq 0\right\}$

However, such inequality seems not to always hold, as we know nothing about the signs of the coefficients of the objective function, besides the fact that the constraints form a polyhedron as a feasible region. The reverse sign is also not correct for **every** cases, I think. So I abandon this approach.

**2nd approach:**

Define optimal solutions $x^{*}$ for K, and $x_{1}^{*},x_{2}^{*}, \ldots, x_{M}^{*}$ for $min_{x} \left\{p_kc^Tx + p_kq_k^Ty_k |\ Ax = b; \ T_kx + W_ky_k = h_k; y_k\geq 0, x\geq 0\right\}$ $\forall \ k=1,2,\ldots, K$.

By the sake of contradiction, assume $K =  \sum_{k=1}^{M} min_{x} \left\{p_kc^Tx + p_kq_k^Ty_k |\ Ax = b; \ T_kx + W_ky_k = h_k; y_k\geq 0, x\geq 0\right\}$. This is equivalent to:

$$c^Tx^{*} = \sum_{k=1}^{M} p_kc^Tx_k^{*}$$.

However, note that $Ax^{*} = Ax_{1}^{*} = Ax_{2}^{*} =\ldots  = Ax_{M}^{*} (\ =\  b)$, and $T_kx^{*} = T_kx_{1}^{*} =\ldots  = T_kx_{M}^{*}$. So, does the first set of equality imply $x^{*} = x_{1}^{*} = x_{2}^{*} = \ldots = x_{M}^{*}$, if $A$ is an invertible matrix?? But if that's the case, shouldn't this means $\sum_{k=1}^{M} p_kc^Tx_k^{*} = c^Tx^{*}\sum_{k=1}^{M} p_k = c^Tx^{*}$ (since $\sum_{k=1}^{M}p_k = 1$)? But this implies the claim above is wrong...

**My question:** Could someone please help review my attempt above, and let me know how you could arrive at the desired contradiction, or if the claim is actually false? Any other suggestions for other approaches would be really appreciated.

Comment: The claim is clearly false when all parameters that depend on $k$ are $0$.

Comment: Actually, we assume the parameters are different from each other for different values of $k$. My bad for not stating it. The formulation I presented is just the deterministic version of the two-stage stochastic LP, in case you are wondering where the term $\sum_{k=1}^{M} p_kq_k^{T}y_k$ and the condition $T_kx+W_ky_k = h_k$ comes from. I added the clarification on this in the OP. Mind giving it another try?

Comment: Under that condition it is still trivial to construct a counterexample. For example, take $c = e_1$ (the first unit vector), let the first column of $T_k$ be $0$ (so that the optimal $x$ does not depend on $y$), and let the constraints force $y$ to $0$.

Comment: @LinAlg: thanks a ton!! I am not sure I follow this line: "first column of $T_k$ is $0$ makes the optimal $x$ not depending on $y$." $x$ is a column vector, so if only the first column of $T_k$ is $0$, then only the first component of optimal $x$ does not depend on $y$, but the remaining component obviously would. Also, the only way to force $y = 0$ is to have $x = T^{-1}h$. But this does not always hold for random values of $(T_k, W_k, h_k, y_k)$. Is this a well-known theorem in two-stage SLP?

Comment: The remaining part of $x$ does not affect optimality due to my choice of $c$. Why do you mention random values? Don't we know the values upfront, and can't we select them to create a counterexample?

Comment: @LinAlg: oh, I missed your $c=e_1$ part (thought $e_1$ is a unit vector. My bad;p). The reason I mentioned random value is because I am afraid that we might misunderstand the problem statement. Yes, we know the values of $(T_k, W_k, h_k, y_k)$ up-front though, since the problem said $\zeta$ follows the discrete distribution.